# Node-machine-id package is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

I am using node-machine-id package 1.1.10 and electron.js 1.7.9 ,react 16.2. 
And My os is windows 10. 
I am tring to get the machine-id but it's not working.

```
import {machineId, machineIdSync} from 'node-machine-id';
let id = machineIdSync();
```

But It's now shown that errors

```
Failed to compile.

Error in ./~/node-machine-id/dist/index.js
Module not found: 'child_process' in G:\electron-with-create-react-app-master\EXO\node_modules\node-machine-id\dist

 @ ./~/node-machine-id/dist/index.js 1:82-106 1:18078-18102
```

I have no way to solve this problem. 
Please contact me and help me. 
Tian yang

Answer (score 2):

> Module not found: 'child_process'

This error seems to indicate you're running this in the renderer process. `child_process` is a node module and can only be accessed from the main process. Renderer processes can only access standard web oriented modules.